# Are there White Powers in Ravenloft, or was that our DM’s invention?

Tags: ravenloft

Soo many, many years ago when the 3rd Edition was the latest edition in the game, we had a big Campaign in the Ravenloft in 2nd (cause old school guys) that we played for almost 4-5 years.

During our time in the Mist, we found out a LOT of the Ravenloft Lore.  This was mainly because our DM was a huge fan of the Ravenloft setting, and had every novel and every other official source: Invidia to Pharazia to the small islands in the west part of the plane.  But one thing came to me; looking back at the memory lane it is still not clear to me if it was from official source or if it was from the DM's mind.

In our latest adventures we learn that the Dark Powers are not the only Powers there: that there is, in a smaller number, something called the White Powers (or something synonymous with good). Has anyone ever read in a Ravenloft novel something like that?

**Is the existence of the White Powers canon, or it an invention of our DM?**

Comment: "This was mainly because our DM was a huge fun" I'd change the u to an a but I have to edit more than one letter.

Comment: Why not ask your GM?

Comment: We didn't stay in touch all those years.

Comment: *White Powers* is a deeply unfortunate naming convention.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Particularly as the complement to *Dark Powers* would be *Light Powers*.

Comment: @Upper_Case I'd disagree that it's the lack of parallelism that make it *particularly* unfortunate, but I will confirm that—as a grammarian—I do find that offensive *also*.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'd only meant that, aside from the term itself being unfortunate, it's not even the opposite of *Dark Powers* (which was presumably the intent, to name them in opposition to that group)-- it both has negative connotations from the phrase itself and also is not suggested by the grammar. Were they placed in opposition to a group called the *Black Powers* (which would also not be great), there would at least be a natural case for *White Powers*.

Comment: @Upper_Case It's cool. No, really, I got it. I just couldn't put the `:-)` after my comment for fear that it would be misinterpreted. All good. Here. Have another one: `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sorry! I'm terrible at reading tone in comments ;p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are White Powers.  But they can only act indirectly to challenge the Dark Powers, in the demiplane of Ravenloft.  See the novel 'Lord of the Necropolis' by Gene Deweese.  This the excerpt from that novel when they are revealed.

P.S. When Azalin talks about his "tormentors" he is referencing the Dark Powers.

[image: The White Powers revealed and speculated on]

Comment: I think this would be even better if it had a more description of what the white powers are like, or what sort of indirect challenges they are known to have performed. Otherwise, good find.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @GregorySnipe these 'Light Powers' appears only in these two pages of this book or there is more pages? (I'm just curious)

Answer (score 8):

### There is no such thing as "White Powers"

Not officially, at least. Mind you, I'm no *expert* in Ravenloft, having read only the 2nd edition core book, 3rd edition core book, nearly all the creature books (Van Richten's guides and bestiaries), and maybe a dozen adventures. Other than that, I have browsed the [Mistpedia](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Main_Page) extensively when creating my own campaigns. That said, my knowledge is missing *several* Ravenloft lore books and novels.

But I never heard the term *White Powers* until today. Which leads me to assume that your GM made that up, for reasons known only to him.

The [Dark Powers](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/The_Dark_Powers) are an unknown entity formed in the plane of shadows, which the sole purpose is to give torment to evil souls. There is no clear definition of who and what they are, which is intentional to keep that *mysterious air* (or mist) about them.

If there is ever anything doing *"good"* in Ravenloft, it's the Dark Powers tormenting a dark lord under a false disguise, or another entity entirely, like a demon or devil, or even corrupted celestials that are doing something *for the greater good*, oblivious of their evil-doings. An example of that are the [Living Gods](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Category:Living_Gods), which are mortals who attempted to become real gods and failed, turning into half-fiends who act as *real gods* on their region.

It isn't disclosed how deities like [Horus](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Osiris) or [the Morning Lord](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/The_Morninglord) work exactly in the dark realms, but it's certain that certain deities are darker and/or corrupted versions of their real versions outside of Ravenloft, like [Belenus](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Belenus_(Deity)). But one thing is known, divine worshippers feel disconnected once they enter Ravenloft, taking a few hours or even days to adjust, sometimes having to call for another god to get their powers again. This is called the *Unspoken Pact*, and there is no clear conclusion about why and how it happens.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that the Dark Powers provide power to clerics in the Demiplane of Dread in place of the actual deities - with the curious effect that the dogma of a given deity's followers in Ravenloft may drift without that deity's clerics losing their powers, even to the point where the Ravenloft version of a deity has a different alignment to the real version outside.

Comment: @GMJoe you are correct, but that is merely one theory on the *Unspoken Pact*. It can be found on the 3e ravenloft setting book.